# Dijit/ComboBox populated by store: disable option/item

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, dijit.form

I'm using the Dijit/ComboBox with a datastore to populate it similar to this example from Dojo:

```
var stateStore = new Memory({
    data: [
        {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
        {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
        {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
        {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
        {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
        {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
        {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
        {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
        {name:"California", id:"CA"},
        {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
        {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
        {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
    ]
});

var comboBox = new ComboBox({
    store: stateStore,
    queryExpr: "*${0}*",
    searchAttr: "name",
});

domConstruct.place(comboBox.domNode, this.inputWrapper)
```

Now I want to disable certain options from the stateStore, so that these are displayed but not selectable. Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20046702/1462656

Comment: That answer is about FilteringSelect instead of ComboBox and uses a declarative markup instead of a datastore...

Comment: try it this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/18737965/1462656 - unfortunately ComboBox doesn't have the getOptions() method

Comment: Why don't you just delete this Items? Or should they be selectable later?

Comment: Because then the user has no knowledge of the fact that the options are there but currently not available.